# Check convergence of integral $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{\sin(x)}{x^2} dx$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Check convergention of integral
$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{\sin(x)}{x^2} dx$

It looks to me like it converges to 0 because it is odd function, but I don't know whether is it enough as a proof. And if it is not, what can I do?

Comment: This integral does not converge using std. definition of improper integrals. Look at the singularity around $0$.

Comment: The principal value is zero.

Answer (score 0):

If $f$ is odd and $I=\int_0^a f(x) dx$ is finite (e.g. with $a=\infty$), $\int_{-a}^0 fdx=-I$ and $\int_{-a}^a fdx=I-I=0$. Since $\infty-\infty$ is an indeterminate form, this result does not generalise to the case $I=\infty$.

For $x>0$, $\frac{\sin x}{x^2}$ is bound between $\pm x^{-2}$, so $\int_\epsilon^\infty\frac{\sin x}{x} dx$ is bound for any $\epsilon >0$ between the finite values $\pm\int_\epsilon^\infty\frac{dx}{x^2}=\pm\frac{1}{\epsilon}$. If $\epsilon$ is small, $\frac{\sin x}{x^2}\approx\frac{1}{x}$ for $x\in [0,\,\epsilon]$, preventing the integral's convergence (under the usual definition). What you're trying to do is a bit like $\int_{-\epsilon}^\epsilon\frac{dx}{x}$.